# leveled compaction not compacting to higher level

Tags: cassandra

Switched from STCS to LCS by altering the table - version 3.11.3

`ALTER TABLE table WITH compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.LeveledCompactionStrategy', 'unchecked_tombstone_compaction': 'true'};`

Now I see there are sstables with default size 160mb, now I see over 100 160mb sstables.

1. When the initial conversion happens, the files which got created are they L0?
2. If so, when do they get compacted to L1, its been couple of hours and auto compaction is enabled. I still do not see them getting compacted to higher level.
3. The default size of 160mb, is it for L0 or L1?
4. What will be the size of sstable which gets flush to become sstables? will they be 160mb or smaller?
5. After how many files are created in each level, does it get compacted to next level?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite expected by default (sstable_size_in_mb = 160 mb) with LCS.

L1 and above are normal levels . L0 is just placeholder and can have overlapping data and any size of sstables.
In normal level two sstables are not overlapping meaning no two sstable can have same partition. So for reading a partion we only need to check one sstable.

> When the initial conversion happens, the files which got created are
>   they L0? If so, when do they get compacted to L1, its been couple of
>   hours and auto compaction is enabled. I still do not see them getting
>   compacted to higher level.

->L0 is full like 32 sstables, It uses SCTC in L0 to make sstables count down. You can check the nodetool tablestats to get the number of sstables in each level

You need to run nodetool repair-full when changing replication strategy, check [this](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsChangeKSStrategy.html) for procedure.

> The default size of 160mb, is it for L0 or L1? What will be the size
>   of sstable which gets flush to become sstables? will they be 160mb or
>   smaller?

-> Only L0 can have sstables on any size.
Normal Level N has 10^N *160 MB sstables (where N>=1). So LCS has fixed size sstables in normal levels but the total size will increase as we go to higher levels (eg: L1(1.6G), L2 (16G) and so on)

> After how many files are created in each level, does it get compacted
>   to next level?

->In normal level, each level need to accommodate 10x more sstables to go to 1 level higher.

Comment: Can we set lower or higher value instead 10? Is there any parameters?

Comment: fanout_size has been configurable now as per CASSANDRA-11550. But why do you want to change that ?

Comment: If we can set 15 or above instead of 10 then higher level can keep most of the data. it may improve read latency if I am not wrong?

Comment: It may improve read performance by touching less number of sstables during read as there will be less number of levels but again you need to keep eye on compaction io.

Comment: Is there any formula or rule behind max level nums? What if I increase it to 10 or reduce it to 3